# Loud fan noises in latest update for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Ever since the latest update, Windows 10 has been freezing and the fan noises have gotten louder. A few updates ago, Windows 10 had a troubleshooting feature called "hardware" which took care of these issues but it seems they got rid of it for some reason. How do I make Windows run smoothly without these fan noises?

Comment: I can guarantee you that the noises you are hearing are not caused by an update to Windows.  You are attempting to correlate the crashes, likely caused by hardware, to an update.  You will have to be more specific on what issues were actually solved though by editing your question.

Comment: Is there a way to run a scan on hardware to see what issues there may be? Windows used to have this in the Settings > Troubleshooting section but it's gone now. It was so useful.

Comment: The Troubleshoot section still exists within the Settings application.

Comment: Right, but HARDWARE is gone now.